# Laravel home page not loading

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

While typing https://deepdivecms.test/ in Chrome it returns the following error

Warning: require(/home/vagrant/Code/deepdivecms/public/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vagrant/Code/deepdivecms/public/index.php on line 24
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0011  392400  {main}( )   .../index.php:0

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/vagrant/Code/deepdivecms/public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/vagrant/Code/deepdivecms/public/index.php on line 24

in my homestead.yaml file, I have put

sites:
    - map: deepdivecms.test
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/deepdivecms/public

Also in the host file i have updated

192.168.10.10 deepdivecms.test

Comment: Did you do `composer install` in your project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run `composer install`. If that doesn't work, try `composer dump-autoload` to generate your autoload classmap.

Comment: As a side note, ensure that *composer install* is ran from the main directory (where your composer.json file is located).

Comment: should i run composer install in C:\laravel-projects\deepdivecms or on C:\Homestead.  both folders have composer.json file

Comment: Yes not the error is disappered, now i get a screen in which it says 'oops something went wrong'

Comment: Run it from the project root (deepdivecms). Have you generated your key? `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: I run "laravel new myproject" and I got the same error today due to my php is 5.6. "laravel new myproject" could not finish building the app, due to it requires php7 now. composer install would fail too due to the same reason. I upgraded my php to php 7 and rerun the laravel new ..., then everything is fine. In simple words, upgrade to php7 before run laravel new to create new app.